# option to lock "interesting tags" section so 'x' isn't hit accidentally on a tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

When I go to the front page of Stack Overflow, I normally hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and hit each of my tags so I can pull up a different browser tab for each tag that I have in my "Interesting tags" section.  About every third time I go through this sequence, I accidentally hit the 'x' next to a tag and delete the tag.  If I had an option to lock the tags (or a tag was somehow slightly more difficult to accidentally delete) I could avoid this annoyance.

Comment: Yeah I've done that a few times and have to go find another tab where I can figure out which one I accidentally deleted. very annoying! :(

Comment: Me too.  I requested the ability to reorder the tags here http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/arrange-favorite-tags.  Locking would at least keep me from shooting myself in the foot.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29584/can-we-get-a-little-doohickey-to-undelete-a-tag-from-interesting-tags

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61704/the-remove-icon-on-interesting-tags-is-easily-misclicked

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30827

Comment: Yes! Do this please.

Answer (score 23):

Perhaps the tags should only be editable from the user profile? Or one can add tags on the main page, but go to the user profile to remove them (or adjust their order, which I believe has been requested before).

Comment: This seems logical to me.

Answer (score 5):

You could completely remove the `'x'` buttons by Ad-blocking the rule

```
stackoverflow.com##div#interesting-tags span.delete-tag
```

The tag can still be removed from "Interesting Tags" by going to the tag's page, mouse-over on that tag, and click the ★ at the top-left corner in the info box.

Comment: +1 working like a charm - still suggest it is implemented anyway, especially as Jeff blogged about exactly this sort of problem http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html

Comment: Now what a shame that I have to enable AdBlock on SO instead of them removing an obvious UI defect.  I have accidentally deleted favorite tags so often that it's not funny anymore.

Comment: This solution is interesting, because I installed adblock _for_ this bug and now I don't see SO's ads anymore.  I didn't have adblock installed before..

Answer (score 0):

The specific behavior that I use to open up the tags is to press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key and then hit each of my favorite'd tags.  This causes firefox/chrome to open up each tag page in a new tab while not changing focus to the new tab.  Similarly  the <kbd>shift</kbd> key causes a link to open up in a new window.

I'm not sure if javascript supports this, but one specific fix to this issue would be to only delete a tag if neither the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key nor the <kbd>shift</kbd> key are pressed.