# The remove icon on interesting tags is easily misclicked

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-watching, ignored-tags

[image: In 11 months, all you've done is make the problem worse]

The safe clickable area for selecting a favorite tag (especially for one letter tags, illustrated above) is quite small compared to the size of the remove button right next to it.  Considering that the user is **much** more likely to want to filter by a tag rather than delete it, how about we move that option somewhere else.

Jeff even wrote about [this situation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html) on Coding Horror.

Comment: +1 for moving it to the user page.  Right now, it's especially easy to do on a phone.

Comment: I've ever requested adding a confirm dialog: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30827/confirm-dialog-when-an-interesting-or-ignored-tag-is-to-be-deleted

Comment: Yes, but classic confirmation is quite annoying

Comment: This is feature request not bug, please retag accordingly. :)

Comment: No, it is about or removing `z` at all, or adding some new UI for suppressing accidental tag removing

Comment: @fl00r WTH? I am 90% sure that when I posted that comment I had no more `x` in my tags. I was so pleased I came to meta, searched to find an announcement about it, found this request and left my comment.

Comment: This is especially bad on short tags like `c` or `r`, where the "delete" icon takes up most of the clickable area.

Comment: @hammar: Exactly, i was about to post a question but i thought that this had to be asked before (ans of course it has)...

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29584/can-we-get-a-little-doohickey-to-undelete-a-tag-from-interesting-tags

Comment: Adding a bounty because it's been brought up many times stretching back at least 11mos and seems to be universally supported.  I would really like to see a solution to this, it is something that bothers me at least a few times a week.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29350/option-to-lock-interesting-tags-section-so-x-isnt-hit-accidentally-on-a-tag

Comment: I come across this problem almost every day when browsing with an ipad. My finger is too big to safely click the word not the cross ( and I have tiny delicate lady fingers!) plus 1.

Comment: Why has nothing been done about this yet?

Comment: We've decided to hide the close X's and the add text boxes by default and use a "modify favorites" text link to activate them.  Clicking outside the area will return to the default state.

Comment: This is now live on meta. We ended up going with an edit link instead of a modify favorites link.

Comment: FINALLY! Next step: allow tags to be dragged in the desired order while in edit mode.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell think it's better be posted as answer, more easy to see less likely to get buried unnoticed. :)

Comment: @JeremyTunnell: what exactly changed?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Was going to post it as an answer but saw that there are an awful lot of votes to overcome.   Probably should.

Comment: @Jeremy OP here will hopefully mark as accepted overriding any votes. If he won't get around maybe add new feature that bounty points also count when sorting by votes, I will give 500 bounty and it will jump to the front as well. ;)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Well, you can also remove it from within the box itself by clicking the highlighted star:

> [image: remove fav tag]

So the additional **X** is indeed not really required - I agree for its removal.

Comment: I like this solution the best.

Comment: Hope this gets implemented soon.

Comment: Yes please! It drives me crazy!

Comment: Not bad, but I prefer the [Pelshoff's solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61704/the-remove-icon-on-interesting-tags-is-easily-misclicked/104494#104494), because it is more intuitive to new users.

Answer (score 31):

Yes! This is annoying.  I have accidentally deleted my *favorite*, favorite tags a few times and it shifts the tag order in annoying ways.

[image]

### Proposed fix:

1. Kill those X's.
2. Add a delete link that opens a pop-over dialog.
3. The dialog uses checkboxes to select tags to remove from the list.  All checkboxes should default as unchecked.

[image: Possible fix]

Comment: What about adding the ability to reorder the tags by drag and drop? This will solve the whole "order" issue. :)

Comment: Like this solution!

Answer (score 21):

We've pushed out changes to this on meta. Feedback always welcome:

- The text fields and advanced tag management link are now hidden behind an edit link in the header of each section
- Clicking on edit reveals the add text box and button and also adds X's to the tags.
- Clicking anywhere outside the favorite/ignored area returns the tags and form to the default state

Hopefully this should eliminate the problem of accidentally removing tags, and I think it looks better to not have hanging form fields in the right sidebar.

Comment: Nice work around, when will this be pushed to all sites? By the way just picky... why you report this and not Oded who [appears to be the one doing it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172502/152859)? ;)

Comment: I like the changes, the solution is rather similar to [my own feature request on that topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170050/simplify-the-favorite-ignored-tags-ui-by-default).

Comment: I'm just pitching in to help.  I did the wireframes, and he's doing the code.  I've currently have him quite busy on several other things so I thought I'd take care of this.

Comment: @MadScientist I may have subconsciously used some of your ideas when I was doing the wireframes but forgot where they came from.

Comment: I didn't notice anything changed because I have no favorites on Meta. So when you add your first tag you're in "edit" mode, without realizing there even *is* an edit mode.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Basically, yes. However, you should keep in mind that the edit state looks exactly like the old default state.  But when you click outside the area, it will clean itself up automatically.

Comment: Cheers, wish there was a way to bump your answer to the front...

Comment: I just noticed this on SO right now. Did it just get pushed to all sites?

Comment: Nicely done ....

Comment: I know "thanks too" are discouraged, but i can't help. You did a really good job and it surely improved those favorite tags, there is no need to stop and double check the mouse position anymore before clicking.

Answer (score 15):

It happens to me all the time, and is quite irritating. I think a confirmation dialog would be great, especially since re-adding a favorite tag, puts it at the end of the line, changing the order you had them in.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm pretty sure that I've never _intentionally_ removed one of my favorite tags, but also manage to do it quite frequently.

Answer (score 5):

For those who like [userscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey): [[Script on StackApps]](https://stackapps.com/questions/2540/remove-delete-favourite-tag-buttons-script)

Answer (score 5):

I was having this problem as well today. Would it be an idea to add a small time delay before actually activating the delete button within the tag? A quick point and click would trigger the tag, a short (~0.5sec?) delay would activate the delete button and make it clickable.

Comment: This is a very good solution!

Comment: I came up with a similar idea today, when I asked the same question (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151683/190341). I would say that this is nice, but only works for users on an actual computer. This won't work properly on touch devices, as you don't have a `hover`-state.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many users I can speak for, but I frequent a few less-prominent tags, and it's a very common use case for me to click a couple of my Interesting Tags to go see what's happening.

On shorter tag names, the delete button can often occupy up to a *third* of the button's area. This hardly seems ideal for a button that surely cannot be intentionally clicked that frequently.

The sum of the question votes [for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61704) [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29350) [four](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29584) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30827) (all addressing the same issue) is currently **96**, which would make it the [fourth most popular feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=requests).

<sup>Yes, I know, I could just take that extra half-second to make *absolutely sure* I don't click that delete circle. But all those half-seconds add up. That's like, 30 seconds of my life!</sup>

Comment: you didn't count [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107041/one-letter-favorite-tags-are-likely-to-be-deleted-instead-of-selected) so it's **99**. :-)