# Delete-button makes it too easy to accidentally remove my favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [The remove icon on interesting tags is easily misclicked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61704/)

I often accidentally click on the "delete" button near my favorite tags instead of clicking on the tag, and I need to add them to my favorites again and again. I think this is a bad user experience.

I don't think that the classic confirmation window is a good solution here. It is annoying. It can be an inline drop-down menu (on hover), or it can be removed at all. We can remove these tags in a special interface in the setting page, and I don't think that it is common user experience to remove tags from the main page.

[image: Picture of delete button problem]