# Delete Favourite Tag button too close to the Tag itself

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“Delete” icon near my favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87677/delete-icon-near-my-favorite-tags)
>   [option to lock “interesting tags” section so 'x' isn't hit accidentally on a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29350/option-to-lock-interesting-tags-section-so-x-isnt-hit-accidentally-on-a-tag)

I very often want to look at my favourite tags. I very rarely want to delete a favourite tag. I certainly don't want to accidentally delete a favourite tag while trying to click on the tag itself.

Can we move favourite/ignored tag management away from the tags themselves? I think there is an [opposite of Fitt's law](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html) problem here.

Comment: doh, yep its totally a dup, wonder why my search didn't show that one up

Comment: ah-hah, its US/UK spelling thing, i searched with the UK spelling of favourite and got no useful hits, with the US spelling there are indeed easy to find dups

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me all the time, and is quite irritating.  I think a confirmation dialog would be great, especially since re-adding a favorite tag, puts it at the end of the line, changing the order you had them in.

Comment: I disagree, I think the delete should be on your profile page or similar - if you keep banging into something its better to move it then cover it with cushioning

Comment: @jk., that's a fine idea also.