# Why was this closed instead of merged, especially considering the activity?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, meta, merged-questions

[Question 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87677/delete-button-makes-it-too-easy-to-accidentally-remove-my-favorite-tags) vs [Question 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61704/interesting-tags-small-widths-and-the-ejection-seat)

I really could care less about question 2 being older, noone cared about it...

Comment: Conspiracy theory: The link to codinghorror!

Comment: Definitely should have been merged or even better, Question 2 being closed as duplicate of Question 1 instead of the other way around.

Comment: Yes, i also think that closing the other way around would have been a better move here.

Comment: I've flagged it asking for dupe-reversal.

Comment: Flagged it because I was whining about this MONTHS ago.  Really I don't care which question is dominant, clearly mine didn't generate much interest even with the codinghorror link.  As long as the point is made that this has been brought up before, I'm fine with it.

Comment: @James: More important than that it has been brought up before is in my opinion that not only two people agree on this (as it has been asked twice) but that pretty much *everyone* agrees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fine, I merged them. So now they are merged. Enjoy.

Comment: Great! Now you only need to remove those little delete buttons from the tags :)

Comment: Now my hopelessly out of date question is the lead?