# Change the width used for the tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The remove icon on interesting tags is easily misclicked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61704/the-remove-icon-on-interesting-tags-is-easily-misclicked)

Ok, maybe I’m a sloppy mouser, but it would make my life a lot easier if the width of [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) was just a few pixels wider. That would push the "remove this tag" button a little bit farther to the right.

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "close tag" button? You mean removing the tag from the Favorite Tags list?

Comment: Minimum tag width doesn't sound at all as a bad idea.

Comment: @Shadow, I assume so.  And having accidentally removed C from my favorite tags list more than once, I agree with the suggestion.