# One-letter favorite tags are likely to be deleted instead of selected

Tags: discussion, user-interface, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The remove icon on interesting tags is easily misclicked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61704/the-remove-icon-on-interesting-tags-is-easily-misclicked)

I wondered where I did lost my favorite tag `r` and then I realized that **I must have accidentally clicked on the cross instead and delete it from my favourites!!** :-) No wonder if you see how big is the cross and how big is the actual tag:

[image]

Wouldn't it be better to add some left padding to the cross so that the clickable area is larger than the cross area?

(uuuh, and also, as I had to add the tag again now it is not in my favourite place at the top of all the tags... some drag-n-drop feature to reorganize tag order would be nice :-) that's a different question but not unrelated...)

Comment: If you search for "favorite tags" you'll see other requests to be able to reorganize them.