# Simplify the favorite/ignored tags UI by default

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, tag-watching

Currently, the favorite and ignored tags section in the sidebar directly allows one to add new tags and remove existing ones. At least for me, adding and removing tags is something I do only occasionally, by far the most common use is passive, using the tags to navigate.

This is how my tag area in the sidebar looks on SO:

[image: Old Tag UI]

And this is how I would propose to change it:

[image: New Tag UI]

The default view (if you have already at least one tag set as favorite or ignored) would be the passive view, that would not allow for editing of the tags. If you wanted to edit, you would click on "manage tags" which would expand the tag UI to the current state.

There are several reasons why I would change this:

- The current approach wastes a lot of space on the rarely used form field to add tags. The forms are also rather eye-catching due to the high contrast on the buttons, this emphasizes a rather less important part of the page.
- It is currently very easy to accidentally remove a tag. As there is no warning or undo, you have to add the tag again manually, which is rather annoying. Making the default view read-only would remove this problem.

Comment: I think the way the current interface shows watched/ignored tags in the sidebar effectively does exactly what this request suggests. Are you okay with this one being marked as [status-completed]?

Answer (score 6):

This is a great solution to the [accidental tag removal problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61704/13295).

It would also really compact that part of the page because of the `x` icon being removed from the tags.

The default view could be a line that says *manage favorite/ignored tags >>*.