# Tag Subscription gone

Tags: bug, status-completed, homepage

I entered today in SO and there is not the small hyper-link to "Tag Subscription>>" that was on the right side of the page anymore. What is happening? is a SO update or it just happens to me?

**EDIT:** Here there is an image of what I am missing.
You can appreciate that below ignored tags there is a "cross-site tag sets >>". In my case it was written "favourite tags >>" or "tags subscription >>" , I don't remember.

[image]

**EDIT2** it looked like this:

[image]

Comment: Tag subscriptions? Did you mean 'favourite tags' perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah sorry, that was what I meant

Comment: on which page since for me its fine and yet [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions) ?

Comment: The feature is still there on the homepage; did you scroll down far enough past the advertisement?

Comment: @NullPonyPointer in SO (Stack overflow), I can't find it

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah yeah, scrolling is not the problem. It is just not there. I'll put a screenshot if it helps, but I assure you that it is not there

Comment: Where exactly that link used to be? Never noticed it. Maybe you installed some user script for that and changed browser?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I didn't have nothing installed... for sure. It was just behind the favourites tag/ignored tags. If I clicked there I would go to the page it is shown on top, to Stack exchange. If I had a subscription on "Matlab" it would show all the SE post with MATLAB tag, in order or activity, newewst or no aswers.

Comment: @AnderBiguri weird, don't recall anything like that.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd that's weird... I had it since the beggining (8 months ago). See the image I edited.

Comment: The image is broken. Please upload using the upload tool here, don't host it on fancy broken hosts. Anyway do you mean such link? http://i.stack.imgur.com/U27Lv.png

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd updated. Yeah! I meant that link. I coudnt fin an image to that!

Comment: Well, the bug is in the homepage layout as Oded just confirmed (and fixed), not with the tags or subscriptions themselves. Retagged this report accordingly.

Comment: I noticed this was fixed on March 20 or so, but as of the 30th "tag subscriptions" seems to be missing again.

Comment: exactly, it is gone again

Comment: @AnderBiguri see my comments [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175037/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yeah, you are right. I actually dont like at all how it is right now, but it totally seems a a design choice. thanks.

Comment: @AnderBiguri still chance it's a simple overlook waiting for Oded to respond on my comment below. :)

Comment: @AnderBiguri per [Oded's response](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172481/tag-subscription-gone/172502?noredirect=1#comment526675_172502) feel free to start new question here on Meta, tagged [meta-tag:feature-request] and ask to always show that link instead of just in edit mode when you already have favorite tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are quite right.

I have been reworking that part of the site and have dropped the link by mistake - the new UI I am working on has moved it.

I have pushed a fix and the link will be reinstated in the next build.

Comment: The link appears only in edit mode of the favorite tags. Is this intentional behavior, or a slight overlook aka a bug?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - It is intentional.

Comment: Fair enough, but people find it annoying (personally I don't really care) you think there's a point for feature request?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - There is always a point to it. I believe the thinking was that it was only relevant if you had favorite tags and it made sense to only show them if one wanted to edit the favorites. But if people have a problem with it, they can raise a feature request (tagged with design).

Answer (score 1):

its still here just careers div got longer so scroll down bit more

[image]

Comment: Well yeah, but yesterday was not like that for me. There was a small hyperlink to "favourite tags" that send me to Stack exchange and I could see and manage the tags from there and see only the question sof that tag, instead of highlighting the ones in SO

Comment: I edited my question