# Missing 'Filtered Question' on right navigation side

Tags: bug, questions, navigation, tag-filters

I noticed the following **problem** for the second time within two weeks (noticed on **stackoverflow.com.**)

I usually see a **link to my filters of stack exchange** (**Filtered Questions**). But today it's the second time within two weeks that **I don't see it**. Is there any reason for that? Am I doing something wrong? I really miss that feature and don't like to switch to stackexchange first and then go to my Filtered Questions.

[image: right navigation bar]

I'm always using the same machine (Mac OS X 10.8.3, Safari 6). Sometimes i see the link. Sometimes not.

Comment: It's visible only when in "edit mode". Click "edit" besides the Favorite Tags and you'll see the link. As far as I can tell it's by design, the devs didn't see reason to always show it.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Well, this is really stupid, i think i'll need a small css hack for that.

Comment: Just  keep [this link](http://stackexchange.com/filters) in your browser's favorites/bookmarks if you use it a lot.