# Misaligned headings on Favorite & Ignored Tags prefs

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I don't have any favorite or ignored tags here on meta, and the [changes recently rolled out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172522/166017) seem to have messed up the alignment when I got to my profile -> prefs. (Happens in Chrome and Safari on OS X 10.8.2)

[image: misaligned favorite & ignored headings]

Can that please be changed to push the "Ignored Tags" heading down to a new line?

While we're at it, it would be great if the "add a favorite tag" and "add an ignored tag" buttons were the same size. Since they appear so close to each other and are *almost* the same size anyway, it would be more aesthetically pleasing for them to have the same fixed width.

Comment: http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi (Chrome stable+Ubuntu precise)

Comment: It's also broken on mobile Safari (iPad iOS 5.0.1)

Comment: @Laura - without a mac here, I can't test. Can you confirm if this is still an issue?

Comment: @Oded Fixed on all my browsers and both my devices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a linebreak to ensure these will show up on separate lines instead of relying on implicit block element behavior.

Comment: Hey just now noticed the OP here works for Stack Exchange... this explains the quick fix! ;)