# Favorite Tag Confirmation on Delete

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Confirm dialog when an interesting (or ignored) tag is to be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30827/confirm-dialog-when-an-interesting-or-ignored-tag-is-to-be-deleted)

Whenever I create a favorite tag like C# the button is extremely small so I occasionally click the X on accident and delete the tag.  Just a suggestion, but it would be nice to have a confirmation prompt when deleting a "Favorites" tag.

Comment: +1 , yes happens with me too.

Comment: C# is *huge*. You should try the c tag, where the X takes up 75% of the tag. :-)

Comment: lol.  Good point.