# Favorite Tags - wouldn't it be nice to be asked before removing a tag or to hide the "x" somehow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The remove icon on interesting tags is easily misclicked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61704/the-remove-icon-on-interesting-tags-is-easily-misclicked)

I click on the "x" on the favorite tags list very often and delete things from this list accidentally. I've read this discussion "[Move the remove tag “X” icon inside the tag in interesting/ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-x-icon-inside-the-tag-in-interesting-ignored-tags) and must say, that even if it's not good looking, it seems more handy. Maybe one of those (or any other) solution could be helpful:

- only double click/double tap deletes the entry
- the "x" is displayed with a little delay (like 200ms), this could be non-practical on mobile devices
- when hitting the "x" the user is prompted to confirm
- only a listing page in the user's profile let me delete my favorite tags

I've about 20 tags in that list. Sometimes I didn't even recognize which one I've deleted.  I also think, that deleting something from the favorites list is not a regular event, so that the overhead from the ideas above shouldn't bother anybody.

Comment: and [Confirm dialog when an interesting (or ignored) tag is to be deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30827)

Comment: @AakashM Thanks for bringing that up. I searched for "Favorite Tags" but didn't go all the way through till 2010. I only came up with the one I've mentioned.