# Interesting Tags + Ignored Tags section: "x" images take too long to appear

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

I'm not sure if anyone else is experiencing this problem, but when I use {Firefox,Chrome} on {Ubuntu,Windows}, the little "x"s that appear next to the tags don't load until about 2 or 3 seconds after the rest of the page. Sometimes I try to be quick and click as many interesting tags sections as a I can to open them all up in new tabs, but occasionally the "x"s appear at the wrong time and I end up either clicking the same tag twice or removing a tag from the list.

Even when the image is cached it still takes a long time to appear. When it does appear, other things happen at the same time, including the highlighting of questions that have "interesting tags" on the main page.

Is there a reason why the "x"s take so long to appear? Are they inserted afterwards by a script?

Comment: Might interest you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29350/option-to-lock-interesting-tags-section-so-x-isnt-hit-accidentally-on-a-tag - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-icon-inside-the-tag

Comment: Are they inserted afterwards by a script? > yes. the tags are just divs in the "interesting tags" section source. the x's are inserted afterwards - with a script block > initTagPrefs() > initDeleteBindings(0)... (run this again and you'll have 2 sets of delete icons)